# How to remove space between two line and make it as one and delete using shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I want remove below part from the file which is added below.

1. Not able to remove `credentials.admin.adapters` this property from file
2. Its deleting the others property in the same line.
3. How to add content between `< >` this character in same line.

   ```
   <!--<UndefineProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters"/>-->
   <!--<AddToProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters"
              value="com.Ldap^cn=Manager^encrypted.com.Ldap.cn=admin"/>-->
   <Property name="credentials.admin.adapters" overridable="true"
         targetFile="Credentials.txt"
         value="com.Ldap^id=proxy"/>
   <!--<UndefineProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters"/>
   <AddToProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters"
              value="com.Ldap^cn=admin^encrypted.com.Ldap.cn=admin"/> -->
   ```

**newconf.txt**

```
<!--<UndefineProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters"/>-->
<!--<AddToProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters"
              value="com.Ldap^cn=Manager^encrypted.com.Ldap.cn=admin"/>-->
<Property name="credentials.admin.adapters" overridable="true"
         targetFile="Credentials.txt"
         value="com.Ldap^id=proxy"/>
<Property name="pom.dbUser" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties"
         value="NM"/>
<Property name="pom.jdbc.host" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties"
         value="0038.rds.amazonaws.com"/>
<Property name="pom.dbPassword" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties"
         value="encrypted.pom.dbPassword"/>
<Property name="pom.serviceName" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties"
         value="rds.amazonaws.com:10:0038"/>
<Property name="pom.jdbc.service" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties"
         value="0038"/>
<Property name="pom.jdbc.port" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties"
         value="10"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="utilities/configurator.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="owl.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="ser.xconf"/>
<!--<UndefineProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters"/>
<AddToProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters"
              value="com.Ldap^cn=admin^encrypted.com.Ldap.cn=admin"/> --><Property 
 name="com.distproc.credential" overridable="true"
         targetFile="distproc.properties"
         value=""/>
 </Configuration>
```

I tried below:

```
sed -i '/value=/N; s/\n\s*/ /g' newconf.txt
sed -i "/credentials.admin.adapters/d" newconf.txt
```

But above code deleting the others property also.

I want below output:

```
<Property name="pom.dbUser" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="NM"/>
<Property name="pom.jdbc.host" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="0038.rds.amazonaws.com"/>
<Property name="pom.dbPassword" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="encrypted.pom.dbPassword"/>
 <Property name="pom.serviceName" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="rds.amazonaws.com:10:0038"/>
 <Property name="pom.jdbc.service" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="0038"/>
   <Property name="pom.jdbc.port" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="10"/>
 <ConfigurationRef xlink:href="utilities/configurator.xconf"/>
 <ConfigurationRef xlink:href="owl.xconf"/>
  <ConfigurationRef xlink:href="ser.xconf"/>          
 <Property name="com.distproc.credential" overridable="true" targetFile="distproc.properties" value=""/>
 </Configuration>
```

Delete below line:

```
 <!--<UndefineProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters"/>-->
<!--<AddToProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters" value="com.Ldap^cn=Manager^encrypted.com.Ldap.cn=admin"/>-->
<Property name="credentials.admin.adapters" overridable="true" targetFile="Credentials.txt" value="com.Ldap^id=proxy"/>
<!--<UndefineProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters"/>
<AddToProperty name="credentials.admin.adapters" value="com.Ldap^cn=admin^encrypted.com.Ldap.cn=admin"/> -->
```

Comment: What's the rationale for which output lines start with blanks and which don't?

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: In your expected output, the first 3 lines start at the start of the line, then the next 2 lines are indented by 1 blank space, then the next lines is indented 3 blanks, then 2 lines indented 1 blank, then 1 line indented 2 blanks, then the final 2 lines indented 1 blank again. Why? What decides how many blanks each output line is indented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -z ':a;s/\([^\n]*\)\n \+/\1 /;ta;s/>\(<[^>]*>\) /\n\1\n/' input_file | sed '/credentials\.admin\.adapters/d'
<Property name="pom.dbUser" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="NM"/>
<Property name="pom.jdbc.host" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="0038.rds.amazonaws.com"/>
<Property name="pom.dbPassword" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="encrypted.pom.dbPassword"/>
<Property name="pom.serviceName" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="rds.amazonaws.com:10:0038"/>
<Property name="pom.jdbc.service" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="0038"/>
<Property name="pom.jdbc.port" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="10"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="utilities/configurator.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="owl.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="ser.xconf"/>
<Property  name="com.distproc.credential" overridable="true" targetFile="distproc.properties" value=""/>
</Configuration>
```

Getting below unstable output:

```
value="NM"/>e="pom.dbUser" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties"
value="0038.rds.amazonaws.com"/>erridable="true" 
targetFile="db.properties"
value="encrypted.pom.dbPassword"/>rridable="true" 
targetFile="db.properties"
value="rds.amazonaws.com:10:0038"/>rridable="true" 
targetFile="db.properties"
value="0038"/>"pom.jdbc.service" overridable="true" 
 targetFile="db.properties"
value="10"/>e="pom.jdbc.port" overridable="true" 
targetFile="db.properties"
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="utilities/configurator.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="owl.xconf"/>
 <ConfigurationRef xlink:href="ser.xconf"/>
```

Comment: I tried this on Online Bash Shell, stil its not working for me.

Comment: @Shr That is impossible, unless you are copying and pasting wrong. Take a look here https://ideone.com/7mwKve  Once again, I think you have your own data you are not sharing with us hence why it does not work for you.

Comment: Have you tried with file input? Check my current o/p.

Comment: Its working for direct input.

Comment: @Shr Share the link to the online resource that did not work. I have seen your output in my suggested edit and you are either doing something very wrong or your input is very different from what has been provided. You refuse to update your question to give realistic samples or expected output, yet, working solutions such as those in this thread do not work for you. I have used all kinds of input and they all work (your provided sample)

Comment: Now I tried in incong mode, its working fine. But same issue facing for on main work

Comment: @Shr Does this work? `sed -z 's/<[^c]*credentials\.admin\.adapters[^>]*>[^<]*\n\?//g' input_file`

Comment: It works !! Thanks you !!! [^c] [^>]*>[^<]* --> Can you explain me this part?

Comment: @Shr Those are non greedy matches. [^c]* - Match everything till the next occurance of a lowercase c. [^>]*> - Match everything up till the next occurance of > and include > in the match.

Answer (score 0):

one big `FS` and 2 calls to `gsub()` is all you need :

```
{m,g}awk '
gsub("[ \t]*\n+[ \t]+"," ",$!(NF=NF))+gsub("[>][\t ]*\n]+[<]",">\n<")^_' RS='^$' OFS=\
FS='([<]!--)?[<][^></=]+=\"credentials[.]admin[.]adapters\"[^>]*[>]( *--[>])?\n*|\n+$'
```

=

```
<Property name="pom.dbUser" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="NM"/>
<Property name="pom.jdbc.host" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="0038.rds.amazonaws.com"/>
<Property name="pom.dbPassword" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="encrypted.pom.dbPassword"/>
<Property name="pom.serviceName" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="rds.amazonaws.com:10:0038"/>
<Property name="pom.jdbc.service" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="0038"/>
<Property name="pom.jdbc.port" overridable="true" targetFile="db.properties" value="10"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="utilities/configurator.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="owl.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="ser.xconf"/>
<Property name="com.distproc.credential" overridable="true" targetFile="distproc.properties" value=""/>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Can I get o/p in sed.

Comment: @Shr : it's just a `regex`. use the `sed -E/-r` flag, and u can pretty much directly copy and paste those over 1-to-1. you need to spend some of ur time actually understanding what those codes are doing and not have us do the `sed` part for u.

Comment: I tried with awk, but its not working at my end.

Comment: show me the error message. ps : `{m,g}awk` is not an actual command name with braces inside it - i meant it as tested and confirmed working for both `mawk` and `gawk`.